# AppEngine .hgignore for Mercurial

Tags: google-app-engine, version-control, mercurial, hgignore

I'm new to AppEngine and I'm not sure what files are necessary and which are not. Does anyone have a solid .hgignore that works for AppEngine/GWT projects?

Answer (score 0):

GWT suggests that you're probably using Java via the Google Plugin for Java on Eclipse. I can't speak to what files are safely ignorable for the GWT side, but from the App Engine side, it's safe to ignore `.class` files, since they'll be regenerated when you deploy. I'd start by keeping everything else, including the `.classpath` and `.project` files and the `.settings` directory, on the theory that it's safer to discover later that you're keeping more than you need than it is to discover the inverse.